# How to access linkedin API in python

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to run the linkedin module to request data from linkedin. I used the instructions from the documentation

```
import linkedin

API_KEY = "123"
API_SECRET = "456"
RETURN_URL = "http://localhost:8000"

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
print (authentication.authorization_url)
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

authentication.authorization_code = "AQTXrv3Pe1iWS0EQvLg0NJA8ju_XuiadXACqHennhWih7iRyDSzAm5jaf3R7I8"
authentication.get_access_token()

application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token='AQTFtPILQkJzXHrHtyQ0rjLe3W0I')

from linkedin import server
application = server.quick_api(

API_KEY, API_SECRET)
```

However the module has no LInkedInAuthentication object. Any Ideas or other modules to use the linkedin API?

Comment: The obvious difference between your example and the documentation is `import linkedin` vs `from linkedin import linkedin`.

Comment: please make sure these are not real API keys...

Comment: Thanks no I just copied them. Not real ones

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
import linkedin
```

do

```
from linkedin import linkedin
```